# Ubuntu 18.04 VM doesn't have any network interfaces

Tags: networking, vmware

I have created VMWare VM from ubuntu 18.04 installed on the physical partition. `ifconfig` shows only `lo`. I tried installing `vmware-tools` bundled with VMWare: they didn't work! I booted the Ubuntu at system boot-up and installed `open-vm-tools` and again booted virtually: they didn't work! I didn't face this issue with previous versions of Ubuntu. I don't know why the good old interfaces file is wrapped with `netplan`.